# Подключение по SSH на новом ПК с использованием старых ключей

Tags: ssh, ssh-key

Скопировал с прошлой машины `~/.ssh/id_rsa` и `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. При попытке подключиться к серверу с авторизацией по ключу получаю ошибку вида `user@server: Permission denied (publickey)`. Права на чтения файлов ключей в порядке.

Где я допустил ошибку и как это это можно исправить? :)

Answer (score 1):

Через несколько попыток ssh выдал мне сообщение

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
user@server: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Я сделал:

```
me@amachine:~$ chown me /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa 
me@amachine:~$ chmod 700 /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

И всё пошло как надо!